# In a Logic When to use For loop and When to use while loop

Tags: java

I am beginner for the programming language , I am bit confused in the basic of looping concept can any one please tell me clearly when to use the concept of For loop and when to use the while loop so that it would be very grace full for me to my future programming,
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

Generally, you use a for loop if you know (Or the program can know at the time of the loop) how many times you want to run a piece of code, and while loops if you do not.

However, it is possible to use them interchangably, so while it may be a bit less elegant to use one than the other, it doesn't matter too much.
Ex:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    do stuff
}
```

is the same as

```
int i = 0;
while(i < 100){
    do stuff
    i++;
}
```

, but the former looks more elegant.

Similarly,

```
bool condition = false;
while(condition){
    do stuff
}
```

and

```
for(bool condition = false; condition;){
    do stuff
}
```

are the same, but generally, the while loop is considered more elegant here.

Comment: @Baadshah: I strongly disagree.  You'd want to provide some use case that proves otherwise.

Comment: @Baadshah that is not true. It might not be elegant but it is possible.

Comment: `for(int i=0; i<3; i++)` is the same as `int i=0; while (i<3) ... i++`

Comment: Yeah may be I missed the point some where.

Answer (score 3):

In almost all cases you could use either for or while loops. You are provided with two ways of looping to help reduce the complexity of your code across different use cases.

**When to use for loops**

For loops are best when you know how many iterations you want to loop before you begin. For example, if you knew you wanted to print the numbers 1 through 10 in order you know you want to loop 10 times.

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
   System.out.println(i);
}
```

**When to use while loops**

While loops are best when you want to continue looping until a specific event occurs or a condition is met. For example, let's say you wanted to print random numbers between 1 and 10 until you came across the number 5. This may take one iteration or hundreds depending on your luck.

```
Random rand = new Random();
int value = 0;
while(value != 5)
{
   value = rand.nextInt(10);
   System.out.println(value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For loops are used when you know how many times you need to `loop`. `While` loops are used to loop until an event occurs.

Also, note that whatever you can do with a for loop, you can do it with a while loop (just add a variable that increments in the while loop and uses it to `break` out of the loop when the variable reaches a certain value).

Answer (score 1):

Basically you should use a for loop if you know the number of iterations this loop has to do. Even if that number is a variable (like the length of a list) it is know at runtime.

A while loop is used when you don't know the number of iteration. You mostly check a condition that can evaluate to false after any number.

You also have the do-while and the for-each loops at your disposal. The do-while is used when you know that you have at least one iteration but the number is otherwise unkown. The for-each is used to iterate over arrays and collections. It can do something for each element contained.

Answer (score 1):

A `for` loop will give you the option to perform any or all of these three things:

- Instantiate a starting iteration value (int i = 0)
- Define a boolean condition on which iteration may continue (i < 10)
- Provide an incrementation step (i += 2)

A valid `for` loop can look like this:

```
for(; ;) {
    System.out.println("This will run forever!!!");
}
```

A `while` loop only gives you the boolean condition, which is **mandatory**.

You typically use the `for` loop when:

- You know the size of the elements you must iterate over

You typically use the `while` loop when:

- You don't know the size of the elements you must iterate over
- You want to busy-wait on some value or variable

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those things that folks typically pick up by experience. First thing to realise is that any for loop can be decomposed into a while loop

```
for ( initialise; test ; go on to next )
```

can be expressed as

```
initialise;
while(test) {
    go on to next
}
```

I'd suggest trying for a little while to use only while loops. What you will then find is that some of your while loops start to feel a little clumsy.

```
initialise;
while(test) {
    my really interesting code here
    go on to next
}
```

and you find that

```
for ( initialise ; test; go on to next ) {
     my really interesting code here
}
```

reads more clearly. One common example being working your way through an array.

```
for ( int i; i < array.length; i++ ){
       something with array[i];
}
```